# How to make TextView in ScrollView focusable to Drag event?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, drag

I have the following layout which displays overlay window which can be dragged in the vertical axis.

Inside the layout are 2 textviews inside the scroll view, blue heading above these textviews can be dragged. But when I trying to drag on textviews inside the scrollview i cannot.

I would like to ask how can I enable dragging in the right way in this case (if is it possible)?

Many thans for any advice.

[image]

```
                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/settingsButtonTop"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/settings"
                    android:src="@drawable/settings"
                    android:tint="@color/white"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="15sp"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/closeButtonTop"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/close"
                    android:src="@drawable/close"
                    android:tint="@color/white"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <!--RESULT (CAN BE DRAGGED)-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <!--ORIGINAL PART-->

                <!--ORIGINAL SETTINGS BAR-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/original_text"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:text="@string/original"
                        android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                        android:textSize="15sp"/>

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/source_lang_spinner"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/main_blue"
                        android:gravity="start"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <!--ORIGINAL TEXT-->
                <ScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/scrollViewSource"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:layout_height="110dp"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewSourceText"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:enabled="true"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:text="@string/lipsum"
                        android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                        android:textSize="15sp"/>
                </ScrollView>


                <!--HORIZONTAL RULE-->
                <View style="@style/Divider"/>

                <!--TRANSLATION PART-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/translated_text"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <!--LANG BAR-->
                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:text="@string/original"
                        android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                        android:textSize="15sp"/>

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/translation_lang_spinner"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/main_blue"
                        android:gravity="start"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <!--TRANSLATED TEXT-->
                <ScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/scrollViewResult"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="110dp"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewTranslatedText"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:text="@string/lipsum"
                        android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                        android:textSize="15sp"/>

                </ScrollView>

            </LinearLayout>
```